# MediaPlayer is lagging while using Handler

Tags: java, android, multithreading

in my Android app I use MediaPlayer and SeekBar. I'd like to update the seekbar automatically, when something plays. I've got this code, but it lags every 1 second. Ive got a suspicion that it should run in a different thread, but I have no idea how to write it. Thanks in advance.

```
private void startPlayProgressUpdater() {
    seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());

    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                startPlayProgressUpdater();
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(notification, 1000);
    } else {

        mediaPlayer.pause();

        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems like a seekBar's problem, it causes lags. I tried to show mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() with a Toast and it was without any lags. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I had to rip off startProgressUpdater() from onProgressChanged() and put it into onStopTrackingTouch().

Comment: How did you end up solving this? I have the same issue.